# Heroku application crashes from memory leak

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, memory, heroku

My ruby application is running out of memory and eventually timing out on heroku's bamboo-ree stack. I logged some Memory usage statistics and ObjectSpace mappings to try and figure out what the problem is. However, it's not really obvious what is causing memory to grow without GC. Is this evident of a C-level memory leak?

Debugging this has proven half the challenge. I did not deploy anything around the time and both the web and background processes are running out out of memory, probably due to a shared resource. I have a database, and redis and memcached shared between them and this seemed [plausible](http://shopify.com/technology/4321572-most-memory-leaks-are-good) but I could not find enough `Dalli#SeverConnectFailures` to justify.

Both processes running out of memory also rules out that any controller or view is responsible for the leak, if that's what is even happening. What other metrics might be interesting to look at?

```
Aug 23 22:43:55 application app/web.17:  Memory usage: 599312 | PID: 2
Aug 23 22:43:57 application app/web.17:  Memory usage: 603972 | PID: 2
Aug 23 22:44:01 application app/web.17:  Memory usage: 603972 | PID: 2
Aug 23 22:44:48 application app/web.17:  Memory usage: 608712 | PID: 2
Aug 23 22:46:12 application app/web.17:  Memory usage: 608712 | PID: 2
Aug 23 22:47:02 application app/web.17:  Memory usage: 603948 | PID: 2
Aug 23 22:47:04 application app/web.17:  Memory usage: 607140 | PID: 2
Aug 23 22:47:12 application app/web.17:  Memory usage: 607148 | PID: 2
Aug 23 22:47:14 application app/web.17:  Memory usage: 613388 | PID: 2
Aug 23 22:47:27 application app/web.17:  Memory usage: 621744 | PID: 2
Aug 23 22:47:31 application app/web.17:  Memory usage: 621744 | PID: 2
Aug 23 22:47:35 application app/web.17:  Memory usage: 622672 | PID: 2
Aug 23 22:48:16 application app/web.17:  Memory usage: 623872 | PID: 2
Aug 23 22:48:30 application app/web.17:  Memory usage: 623872 | PID: 2
Aug 23 22:48:54 application app/web.17:  Memory usage: 623872 | PID: 2
```

---

```
Aug 23 22:28:50 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: String: 280596
Aug 23 22:28:50 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: Array: 109002
Aug 23 22:28:50 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: Hash: 27619
Aug 23 22:28:50 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: Proc: 23485
Aug 23 22:28:50 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: Regin::Character: 22918
Aug 23 22:28:50 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: Regexp: 6827
Aug 23 22:28:50 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: MatchData: 3939
Aug 23 22:28:50 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: Float: 3541
Aug 23 22:28:50 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: Regin::Expression: 3514
Aug 23 22:28:50 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: Class: 3065
Aug 23 22:28:50 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: ActiveSupport::Callbacks::CallbackChain: 2741
Aug 23 22:28:50 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: ActiveSupport::Callbacks::Callback: 2677
Aug 23 22:28:50 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: Regin::Group: 2555
Aug 23 22:28:50 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: Rack::Mount::RegexpWithNamedGroups: 2514
Aug 23 22:28:50 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: Rack::Mount::GeneratableRegexp::DynamicSegment: 2399
Aug 23 22:28:50 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: Regin::Anchor: 1918
Aug 23 22:28:50 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: Module: 1753
Aug 23 22:28:50 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: Regin::CharacterClass: 1602
Aug 23 22:28:50 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: MIME::Type: 1533
Aug 23 22:28:50 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: Gem::Version: 1509
Aug 23 22:28:50 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: Rack::Mount::Route: 1350
Aug 23 22:28:50 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: ActionDispatch::Routing::Route: 1350
Aug 23 22:28:50 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: ActionDispatch::Routing::RouteSet::Dispatcher: 1346
Aug 23 22:28:50 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: Gem::Requirement: 1256
Aug 23 22:28:50 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: Range: 1199
Aug 23 22:28:50 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::Mysql2Column: 1138

Aug 23 22:28:54 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: String: 234917
Aug 23 22:28:54 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: Array: 94791
Aug 23 22:28:54 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: Hash: 28202
Aug 23 22:28:54 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: Proc: 23167
Aug 23 22:28:54 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: Regin::Character: 22918
Aug 23 22:28:54 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: Regexp: 6295
Aug 23 22:28:54 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: Float: 4245
Aug 23 22:28:54 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: Regin::Expression: 3514
Aug 23 22:28:54 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: Class: 3067
Aug 23 22:28:54 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: ActiveSupport::Callbacks::CallbackChain: 2741
Aug 23 22:28:54 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: ActiveSupport::Callbacks::Callback: 2677
Aug 23 22:28:54 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: Regin::Group: 2555
Aug 23 22:28:54 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: Rack::Mount::RegexpWithNamedGroups: 2514
Aug 23 22:28:54 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: Rack::Mount::GeneratableRegexp::DynamicSegment: 2399
Aug 23 22:28:54 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: Regin::Anchor: 1918
Aug 23 22:28:54 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: Module: 1751
Aug 23 22:28:54 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: Regin::CharacterClass: 1602
Aug 23 22:28:54 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: MIME::Type: 1533
Aug 23 22:28:54 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: Gem::Version: 1509
Aug 23 22:28:54 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: Rack::Mount::Route: 1350
Aug 23 22:28:54 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: ActionDispatch::Routing::Route: 1350
Aug 23 22:28:54 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: ActionDispatch::Routing::RouteSet::Dispatcher: 1346
Aug 23 22:28:54 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: Gem::Requirement: 1256
Aug 23 22:28:54 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: Range: 1162
Aug 23 22:28:54 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::Mysql2Column: 1138

Aug 23 22:28:59 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: String: 269014
Aug 23 22:28:59 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: Array: 107634
Aug 23 22:28:59 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: Hash: 29371
Aug 23 22:28:59 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: Proc: 23427
Aug 23 22:28:59 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: Regin::Character: 22918
Aug 23 22:28:59 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: Regexp: 6372
Aug 23 22:28:59 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: Float: 5056
Aug 23 22:28:59 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: Regin::Expression: 3514
Aug 23 22:28:59 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: Class: 3069
Aug 23 22:28:59 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: ActiveSupport::Callbacks::CallbackChain: 2741
Aug 23 22:28:59 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: ActiveSupport::Callbacks::Callback: 2677
Aug 23 22:28:59 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: Regin::Group: 2555
Aug 23 22:28:59 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: Rack::Mount::RegexpWithNamedGroups: 2514
Aug 23 22:28:59 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: Rack::Mount::GeneratableRegexp::DynamicSegment: 2399
Aug 23 22:28:59 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: Regin::Anchor: 1918
Aug 23 22:28:59 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: Module: 1756
Aug 23 22:28:59 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: Regin::CharacterClass: 1602
Aug 23 22:28:59 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: MIME::Type: 1533
Aug 23 22:28:59 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: Gem::Version: 1509
Aug 23 22:28:59 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: Rack::Mount::Route: 1350
Aug 23 22:28:59 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: ActionDispatch::Routing::Route: 1350
Aug 23 22:28:59 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: ActionDispatch::Routing::RouteSet::Dispatcher: 1346
Aug 23 22:28:59 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: Range: 1332
Aug 23 22:28:59 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: Gem::Requirement: 1256
Aug 23 22:28:59 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::Mysql2Column: 1160
Aug 23 22:28:59 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: Time: 1142

Aug 23 22:29:53 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: String: 294645
Aug 23 22:29:53 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: Array: 120647
Aug 23 22:29:53 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: Hash: 30152
Aug 23 22:29:53 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: Proc: 23613
Aug 23 22:29:53 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: Regin::Character: 22918
Aug 23 22:29:53 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: Regexp: 6434
Aug 23 22:29:53 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: Float: 6272
Aug 23 22:29:53 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: Regin::Expression: 3514
Aug 23 22:29:53 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: Class: 3070
Aug 23 22:29:53 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: ActiveSupport::Callbacks::CallbackChain: 2741
Aug 23 22:29:53 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: ActiveSupport::Callbacks::Callback: 2677
Aug 23 22:29:53 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: Regin::Group: 2555
Aug 23 22:29:53 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: Rack::Mount::RegexpWithNamedGroups: 2514
Aug 23 22:29:53 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: Rack::Mount::GeneratableRegexp::DynamicSegment: 2399
Aug 23 22:29:53 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: Regin::Anchor: 1918
Aug 23 22:29:53 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: Module: 1758
Aug 23 22:29:53 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: Time: 1710
Aug 23 22:29:53 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: Range: 1630
Aug 23 22:29:53 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: Regin::CharacterClass: 1602
Aug 23 22:29:53 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: MIME::Type: 1533
Aug 23 22:29:53 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: Gem::Version: 1509
Aug 23 22:29:53 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: Rack::Mount::Route: 1350
Aug 23 22:29:53 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: ActionDispatch::Routing::Route: 1350
Aug 23 22:29:53 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: ActionDispatch::Routing::RouteSet::Dispatcher: 1346
Aug 23 22:29:53 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: Gem::Requirement: 1256
Aug 23 22:29:53 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: MatchData: 1222
Aug 23 22:29:53 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::Mysql2Column: 1160

Aug 23 22:30:19 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: String: 315966
Aug 23 22:30:19 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: Array: 131711
Aug 23 22:30:19 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: Hash: 30602
Aug 23 22:30:19 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: Proc: 23716
Aug 23 22:30:19 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: Regin::Character: 22918
Aug 23 22:30:19 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: Float: 7174
Aug 23 22:30:19 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: Regexp: 6509
Aug 23 22:30:19 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: Regin::Expression: 3514
Aug 23 22:30:19 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: Class: 3074
Aug 23 22:30:19 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: ActiveSupport::Callbacks::CallbackChain: 2741
Aug 23 22:30:19 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: ActiveSupport::Callbacks::Callback: 2677
Aug 23 22:30:19 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: Regin::Group: 2555
Aug 23 22:30:19 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: Rack::Mount::RegexpWithNamedGroups: 2514
Aug 23 22:30:19 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: Rack::Mount::GeneratableRegexp::DynamicSegment: 2399
Aug 23 22:30:19 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: Time: 1998
Aug 23 22:30:19 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: Regin::Anchor: 1918
Aug 23 22:30:19 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: Range: 1803
Aug 23 22:30:19 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: Module: 1764
Aug 23 22:30:19 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: Regin::CharacterClass: 1602
Aug 23 22:30:19 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: MatchData: 1587
Aug 23 22:30:19 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: MIME::Type: 1533
Aug 23 22:30:19 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: Gem::Version: 1509
Aug 23 22:30:19 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: Rack::Mount::Route: 1350
Aug 23 22:30:19 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: ActionDispatch::Routing::Route: 1350
Aug 23 22:30:19 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: ActionDispatch::Routing::RouteSet::Dispatcher: 1346
Aug 23 22:30:19 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: Gem::Requirement: 1256
Aug 23 22:30:19 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::Mysql2Column: 1188

Aug 23 22:30:22 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: String: 283207
Aug 23 22:30:22 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: Array: 106024
Aug 23 22:30:22 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: Hash: 30823
Aug 23 22:30:22 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: Proc: 23815
Aug 23 22:30:22 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: Regin::Character: 22918
Aug 23 22:30:22 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: Float: 7253
Aug 23 22:30:22 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: Regexp: 6657
Aug 23 22:30:22 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: Regin::Expression: 3514
Aug 23 22:30:22 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: MatchData: 3118
Aug 23 22:30:22 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: Class: 3073
Aug 23 22:30:22 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: ActiveSupport::Callbacks::CallbackChain: 2741
Aug 23 22:30:22 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: ActiveSupport::Callbacks::Callback: 2677
Aug 23 22:30:22 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: Regin::Group: 2555
Aug 23 22:30:22 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: Rack::Mount::RegexpWithNamedGroups: 2514
Aug 23 22:30:22 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: Rack::Mount::GeneratableRegexp::DynamicSegment: 2399
Aug 23 22:30:22 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: Range: 2156
Aug 23 22:30:22 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: Regin::Anchor: 1918
Aug 23 22:30:22 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: Time: 1804
Aug 23 22:30:22 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: Module: 1761
Aug 23 22:30:22 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: Regin::CharacterClass: 1602
Aug 23 22:30:22 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: MIME::Type: 1533
Aug 23 22:30:22 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: Gem::Version: 1509
Aug 23 22:30:22 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: Rack::Mount::Route: 1350
Aug 23 22:30:22 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: ActionDispatch::Routing::Route: 1350
Aug 23 22:30:22 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: ActionDispatch::Routing::RouteSet::Dispatcher: 1346
Aug 23 22:30:22 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: Gem::Requirement: 1256
Aug 23 22:30:22 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::Mysql2Column: 1188
Aug 23 22:30:22 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: NewRelic::MetricSpec: 1031

Aug 23 22:30:24 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: String: 245422
Aug 23 22:30:24 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: Array: 88415
Aug 23 22:30:24 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: Hash: 29806
Aug 23 22:30:24 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: Proc: 23347
Aug 23 22:30:24 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: Regin::Character: 22918
Aug 23 22:30:24 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: Regexp: 6615
Aug 23 22:30:24 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: Regin::Expression: 3514
Aug 23 22:30:24 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: Float: 3239
Aug 23 22:30:24 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: MatchData: 3199
Aug 23 22:30:24 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: Class: 3074
Aug 23 22:30:24 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: ActiveSupport::Callbacks::CallbackChain: 2741
Aug 23 22:30:24 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: ActiveSupport::Callbacks::Callback: 2677
Aug 23 22:30:24 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: Regin::Group: 2555
Aug 23 22:30:24 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: Rack::Mount::RegexpWithNamedGroups: 2514
Aug 23 22:30:24 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: Rack::Mount::GeneratableRegexp::DynamicSegment: 2399
Aug 23 22:30:24 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: Regin::Anchor: 1918
Aug 23 22:30:24 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: Module: 1789
Aug 23 22:30:24 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: Regin::CharacterClass: 1602
Aug 23 22:30:24 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: MIME::Type: 1533
Aug 23 22:30:24 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: Gem::Version: 1509
Aug 23 22:30:24 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: Rack::Mount::Route: 1350
Aug 23 22:30:24 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: ActionDispatch::Routing::Route: 1350
Aug 23 22:30:24 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: ActionDispatch::Routing::RouteSet::Dispatcher: 1346
Aug 23 22:30:24 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: Gem::Requirement: 1256
Aug 23 22:30:24 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::Mysql2Column: 1211

Aug 23 22:30:43 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: String: 282894
Aug 23 22:30:43 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: Array: 122259
Aug 23 22:30:43 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: Hash: 33899
Aug 23 22:30:43 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: Proc: 23900
Aug 23 22:30:43 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: Regin::Character: 22918
Aug 23 22:30:43 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: Float: 8009
Aug 23 22:30:43 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: Regexp: 6727
Aug 23 22:30:43 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: MatchData: 3790
Aug 23 22:30:43 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: Regin::Expression: 3514
Aug 23 22:30:43 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: Class: 3075
Aug 23 22:30:43 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: ActiveSupport::Callbacks::CallbackChain: 2741
Aug 23 22:30:43 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: ActiveSupport::Callbacks::Callback: 2677
Aug 23 22:30:43 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: Regin::Group: 2555
Aug 23 22:30:43 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: Rack::Mount::RegexpWithNamedGroups: 2514
Aug 23 22:30:43 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: Rack::Mount::GeneratableRegexp::DynamicSegment: 2399
Aug 23 22:30:43 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: Time: 2377
Aug 23 22:30:43 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: Regin::Anchor: 1918
Aug 23 22:30:43 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: Range: 1827
Aug 23 22:30:43 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: Module: 1795
Aug 23 22:30:43 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: Regin::CharacterClass: 1602
Aug 23 22:30:43 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: MIME::Type: 1533
Aug 23 22:30:43 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: Gem::Version: 1509
Aug 23 22:30:43 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: Rack::Mount::Route: 1350
Aug 23 22:30:43 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: ActionDispatch::Routing::Route: 1350
Aug 23 22:30:43 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: ActionDispatch::Routing::RouteSet::Dispatcher: 1346
Aug 23 22:30:43 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: Gem::Requirement: 1256
Aug 23 22:30:43 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::Mysql2Column: 1211
Aug 23 22:30:43 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: NewRelic::MetricSpec: 1097

Aug 23 22:31:05 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: String: 247487
Aug 23 22:31:05 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: Array: 86538
Aug 23 22:31:05 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: Hash: 35635
Aug 23 22:31:05 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: Proc: 23187
Aug 23 22:31:05 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: Regin::Character: 22918
Aug 23 22:31:05 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: Regexp: 6402
Aug 23 22:31:05 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: Float: 5852
Aug 23 22:31:05 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: Regin::Expression: 3514
Aug 23 22:31:05 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: Class: 3075
Aug 23 22:31:05 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: ActiveSupport::Callbacks::CallbackChain: 2741
Aug 23 22:31:05 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: ActiveSupport::Callbacks::Callback: 2677
Aug 23 22:31:05 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: Regin::Group: 2555
Aug 23 22:31:05 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: Rack::Mount::RegexpWithNamedGroups: 2514
Aug 23 22:31:05 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: Rack::Mount::GeneratableRegexp::DynamicSegment: 2399
Aug 23 22:31:05 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: NewRelic::TransactionSample::Segment: 2200
Aug 23 22:31:05 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: Regin::Anchor: 1918
Aug 23 22:31:05 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: Module: 1777
Aug 23 22:31:05 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: Regin::CharacterClass: 1602
Aug 23 22:31:05 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: MIME::Type: 1533
Aug 23 22:31:05 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: Gem::Version: 1509
Aug 23 22:31:05 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: Time: 1382
Aug 23 22:31:05 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: Rack::Mount::Route: 1350
Aug 23 22:31:05 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: ActionDispatch::Routing::Route: 1350
Aug 23 22:31:06 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: ActionDispatch::Routing::RouteSet::Dispatcher: 1346
Aug 23 22:31:06 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: Gem::Requirement: 1256
Aug 23 22:31:06 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::Mysql2Column: 1211
Aug 23 22:31:06 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: ActiveRecord::Associations::BelongsToAssociation: 1116

Aug 23 22:32:22 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: String: 264877
Aug 23 22:32:22 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: Array: 98195
Aug 23 22:32:22 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: Hash: 38516
Aug 23 22:32:22 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: Proc: 23305
Aug 23 22:32:22 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: Regin::Character: 22918
Aug 23 22:32:22 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: Float: 6633
Aug 23 22:32:22 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: Regexp: 6628
Aug 23 22:32:22 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: NewRelic::TransactionSample::Segment: 4402
Aug 23 22:32:22 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: Regin::Expression: 3514
Aug 23 22:32:22 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: Class: 3075
Aug 23 22:32:22 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: ActiveSupport::Callbacks::CallbackChain: 2741
Aug 23 22:32:22 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: ActiveSupport::Callbacks::Callback: 2677
Aug 23 22:32:22 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: Regin::Group: 2555
Aug 23 22:32:22 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: Rack::Mount::RegexpWithNamedGroups: 2514
Aug 23 22:32:22 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: Rack::Mount::GeneratableRegexp::DynamicSegment: 2399
Aug 23 22:32:22 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: Bignum: 2210
Aug 23 22:32:22 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: Time: 2027
Aug 23 22:32:22 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: Regin::Anchor: 1918
Aug 23 22:32:22 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: Module: 1777
Aug 23 22:32:22 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: Regin::CharacterClass: 1602
Aug 23 22:32:22 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: MatchData: 1574
Aug 23 22:32:22 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: MIME::Type: 1533
Aug 23 22:32:22 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: Gem::Version: 1509
Aug 23 22:32:22 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: Rack::Mount::Route: 1350
Aug 23 22:32:22 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: ActionDispatch::Routing::Route: 1350
Aug 23 22:32:22 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: ActionDispatch::Routing::RouteSet::Dispatcher: 1346
Aug 23 22:32:22 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: Gem::Requirement: 1256
Aug 23 22:32:22 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::Mysql2Column: 1211
Aug 23 22:32:22 application app/web.17:  ObjectSpace: ActiveRecord::Associations::BelongsToAssociation: 1116
```

Comment: Ruby can take on dependencies with C extensions.

Comment: Almost any modern language can that, this is not distinctive and not very helpful. The C community on SO will not be able to help you.

Comment: what's you gemfile and version of ruby?  Are you using fibers or event machine in your application?